# WCF TCP Endpoints Cannot Add Service Reference

Tags: wcf

I've been battling with this one for weeks in my spare-time, determined not to turn to this wonderful community. But my spirit is broken. So ...

I have created a WCF Service and am trying to host it in a Console App, with a view to using a TCP end point.

I have one project which contains the contract and the svc file.
I have another project which contains a Console app, which references the first-mentioned project.
The main method of my Console app looks like this:

```
using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(LicenceBucketWireService.LicenceBucketService)))
{
    host.Open();

    foreach (var endpt in host.Description.Endpoints)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enpoint address:\t{0}",endpt.Address);
        Console.WriteLine("Enpoint binding:\t{0}",endpt.Binding);
        Console.WriteLine("Enpoint contract:\t{0}\n", endpt.Contract.ContractType.Name);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Up til this point, all is dandy:

[image]

It goes awry when I try to add a Service Reference for that service to a 3rd completely separate app which is going to consume that service. When I try to add a reference, using net.tcp://localhost:49189/LicenceBucketWireService/LicenceBucketService/mex as the address for discovering details, I get an error:

> The URI prefix is not recognized.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:49189/LicenceBucketWireService/LicenceBucketService/mex'.
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:49189/LicenceBucketWireService/LicenceBucketService/mex'.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

The console app is running when I perform this task.
The app config has the following element:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="LicenceBucketWireService.LicenceBucketService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="LicenceBucketWireService.ILicenceBucketService"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/licenceBucketService"
          binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="LicenceBucketWireService.ILicenceBucketService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:49187/LicenceBucketWireService/LicenceBucketService" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:49189/LicenceBucketWireService/LicenceBucketService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Change the `httpGetEnabled` attribute to true in your service config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line of code in the config file:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="LicenceBucketWireService.ILicenceBucketService"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
```

should have the contract as "IMetadataExchange" instead of LicenceBucketWireService.ILicenceBucketService.

That should take care of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was so close!